# Letter of Recommendation Expiration Date

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

I have 9 and 10 months old recommendation letters. Can I use these when applying to graduate programs (United States)? Is that okay with the admissions committee?

Comment: It would be much better to ask your writers for updated letters. It should not be very much work for them.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge the problem is that 2 out of 3 recommenders are out of town so it will be very hard to contact them to redo the letters.

Comment: Well, that's what email is for :)  If you've left it too long and they are not able to update their letters before the deadline, you may be able to submit the old ones with your application, and have the writers send the new ones directly to the department as soon as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to other points already made, in most situations *you* do not send the letters yourself, but have the recommenders send the letters *directly*. Sometimes this involves simply uploading the letters to a web site, but this would be done _by_the_recommenders_, not by you.

Thus, some action will be required by your recommenders.

Comment: I wondered about this point a little bit.  However, s/he may mean either that the letters are uploaded to an online service like Interfolio where they can be securely sent out by the recomendee without action by the recommender, or maybe that a staff member in his/her department has the letters and can send out new copies (this was the standard arrangement at Berkeley when I was a student).

Comment: @BenWebster, my current letter-writing for undergrads (in math, for a dozen or so of the better-best schools) _uniformly_ requires that I upload my letters and interact with a site, whence my conclusion. Yes, it would be better to have a centralized/organized site like mathjobs.org, certainly!

Comment: Actually, Interfolio can go through at least some of these systems.  Anyways, this just reinforces the point that the thing to do is talk to the recommenders.

Comment: One of my recommenders told me he doesn't like the current way of writing letters for job applications (one can basically only write one letter) **because** writing "You are as good as Gauss" in a letter to Princeton has completely different meanings from that in a letter to Minnesota business school for instance.

Comment: @ZhouFang I don't understand.  Why can't one write more than one letter?  It's a bit of a pain, I'll admit, but if it bothers you, I don't see what the obstacle is.

Comment: @BenWebster My recommender meant/means that it is sometimes **optimal** to write more than one letter. That is, if one applies for a great range of places, a single letter won't usually suffice. (It _doesn't_ bother me...) Because being as good as Gauss is much harder at Princeton, it would be better to write a different letter to Princeton from that to Minnesota business school.

Comment: @BenWebster In a more straightforward way: a recognized "Gauss" in a business school may probably be regarded as a far secondary mathematician at Princeton. That is, the standards are so different that letters should not be the same.

Comment: @ZhouFang OK; I'm still not I understand the problem.  In your initial comment it sounded like this issue was that your recommender wanted to write multiple versions of the letter and some external force was stopping him; now it sounds like he knows he can do this and that maybe it would be a good thing to do, but he laments the effort involved.

Comment: I don't think anyone **likes** the current way of writing letters.  There's a funny sort of inflation is which one can't say anything negative, and one has to leave the application reviewers to deduce how strong you think the candidate is from just how positive you are.  The fact that you could write many different versions of the letter for different audiences is just one small sub-problem inside a much larger screwed up situation.

Comment: @BenWebster The "external force" is: one can only submit one letter to a centralized server (mathjobs.org) that will distribute this single letter to various universities. Btw, I don't entirely agree that "one can't say anything negative"--e.g., see http://www.rackham.umich.edu/downloads/admissions/RecFormPaper.pdf (one can select "Next 50%" if applicable.)

Comment: @BenWebster Since I've never read/written any letter for graduate school/job applications, I'm not qualified to form any opinion on the differences among all the "positive" comments you described... (But if the differences were huge, ...)

Comment: @ZhouFang I think you misunderstood what I meant by "can't." You are, of course, free to check the "Next 50%" box, if you don't want the person you are recommending to into that graduate school.  But then why are you wasting your time writing the recommendation?  This reveals exactly the problem I was discussing.  If lots of other recommenders don't check that box even if they think the person is in the bottom 50%, how can you in good conscience?  You'd just be hamstringing everyone you recommend.

Comment: @ZhouFang You're wrong about MathJobs.  You can put up as many different versions of your letter as you want, and you can specify exactly which schools can see which.  This is a laziness issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @BenWebster Well, first I think it might be better to use "one" instead of "you". :) **But** is the problem you describe a decisive factor about letter writings? It depends. It depends on the qualifications of recommenders. It depends on the strengthness of the undergard/grad program. It depends on a lot of stuff. "X got a good A in my class" will have completely different meanings as the factors I mentioned above vary. It may be impossible to expect how positive a letter is can address everything.

Comment: @BenWebster I said, that's what my recommender told me. I said, I've never written letters for grad school/job applications.

Comment: @BenWebster Simply put in this way: if Gauss said student A has a _moderate_ talent in math compared with Riemann and I said student B is even smarter than me, which student would you choose?

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Nate Eldredge's point, this would be a bad idea on several levels:

- It will look bad with the committee.  Presumably the letters are dated and people will notice.  It will probably not be interpreted charitably.
- Presumably an updated letter will may more good things about you, since it will mention whatever you've been doing for past 10 months.  Hopefully you've done *something* worth noting in that time.
- It's also bad form to use letters so long after they are written without contacting the authors.  I don't think there are any precise cutoffs for when one transitions from OK to not OK, but I feel like 10 months is pretty firmly in not OK territory.  You need to give the letter writers the chance to update their assessment, hopefully for the better.

I don't understand why people being out of town is a problem for contacting them.  As Nate says, just send them an email. The ball will be in their court, and they can figure out whether it's practical or not.